# Probability on sex distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

The problem comes from Feller's introduction to probability. The problem states:

"Let the probability $p_n$ that a family has exactly $n$ children be $ap^n$ when $n \geq 1$, and $p_0 = 1 - ap(1+p+p^2+...)$. Suppose that all sex distributions of $n$ children have the same probability. Show that for $k \geq1$ the probability that a family has exactly $k$ boys is $\frac{2ap^k}{(2-p)^{k+1}}$"

My problem right now is that i think that the answer may have a typo (lots of answers on the book have them) because if you take the events:

$A = $ The family has $n$ children

$B = $ The family has exactly $k$ boys

Then the required probability is given by $Pr(A\bigcap B) = Pr(B|A)Pr(A)$

By the problem statement: $Pr(A) = ap^n$ and then the conditional probability $Pr(A\bigcap B)$ should be given by $\frac{n\choose k}{2^n}$ (because all sex distributions of $n$ children have the same probability and then probability of exactly $k$ boys will depend on how many ways you can choose those elements given that the family has exactly $n$ children).

But then we get:

$Pr(A\bigcap B) = \frac{{n\choose k}ap^n}{2^n}$

Which is clearly different than the expected answer, so where is my mistake so far?

Comment: The question asks for the probability that a family has exactly $k$ boys. The intersection of the event you wrote is the event of having $n$ children and exactly $k$ of them boys. These are not the same events. Consider the event of $n+1$ children, $k$ of which are boys, or $n+2$ children, or even $k+1$ children, all but one a boy etc. The original event is just concerned with the event of $k$ boys unconditional on the number of children.

Comment: So in that case you could get the desired probability by the sum: $∑Pr(A_j \bigcap B)$ ?

Where $A_j$ is the event in which the family has exactly $j$ children

Comment: Formally if $C$ is the number of children, and conditional on $C=n$, $B$ the number of boys, then $P(B=k)=\sum_n P(B=k|C=n)P(C=n)$ by the LTP.

Comment: (Which you can see is equivalent to your sum by definition of conditional probability, and thru a change of notation emphasizing the events rather than the RVs)

Comment: Ok, so the final answer would be just a simplification of that sum right?

Comment: indeed indeed, though I have not worked it out yet to see if it coincides with Feller’s recorded answer. If I get a moment, I will and perhaps will write up an answer, but if you work it out, do feel free to answer your own question (which is allowed and even encouraged here!)

Comment: Well, thanks for the help i'll get to it right now